# Database, No Value Given for One or More parameter VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm making a program that mangages book issuance and return for our Junior Project and it is nearly finished but there is one problem, I can't seem to insert data. I googled how to but none of them seem to work. I have a module and 5 forms. Here's the module:

```
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset
Public cn As ADODB.Connection
Public sql As String
Public Category As String

Public Function SetCon()
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Database\Database.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
    cn.Open
End Function

Public Function SetRs()
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
End Function

Public Function CloseRS()
    Set rs = Nothing
'End Function

ublic Function CloseCon()
    Set cn = Nothing
End Function
```

And here's the code for my form:

```
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
    frmMain.Show
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDone_Click()
        SetCon
            sql = "SELECT * FROM tblStudents WHERE StudID='" + txtStudID.text + "'"
            SetRs
                cn.Execute "INSERT INTO tblStudents(Books Recieved) VALUES('" + txtBooks.text + "')"
                MsgBox "SUCCESS!!!", vbInformation, "Success!"
        Adodc1.Refresh
        txtStudID.text = ""
        txtBookID.text = ""
    CloseRS
CloseCon
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Call fillbooks
listBooks.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Thanks in advanced ^_^

Comment: I've edited your question to use code formatting so it's easier to read. Check out the help when posting next time to learn how to use it. It has automatic syntax highlighting which is nice. I also noticed your code is invalid at some places (I see a commented out `End Function` and a missing `p` for `ublic`), you may want to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34345507/edit) your question to fix that.

Comment: Also, is your title the error you're getting? You should probably clearly state that in the question.

Comment: It would also be good to formalize a question as `insert data` is vague.

Comment: You may well have other problems, but the error message is most likely because your field name has a space in it. Try using square brackets around the field name, ie `tblStudents([Books Recieved]) ...`

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL Injection, put a `'` in the textbox and see what happens.  Use a parameterized insert.